# Confusing on regular expression using in NSPredicate with ISBN numbers example

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, nspredicate

Apple document gives an example when describing how to use regular expression in NSPredicate.

```
NSArray *isbnTestArray = @[@"123456789X", @"987654321x", @"1234567890", @"12345X", @"1234567890X"];
NSPredicate *isbnPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '\\\\d{10}|\\\\d{9}[Xx]'"];
NSArray *isbnArray = [isbnTestArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:isbnPredicate];
```

My question is why it use `\\\\d` but not `\\d` or `\d` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The regular expression pattern for a digit is `\d`.
- Inside the literal string in `'…'` in the predicate, each backslash has to be escaped, so you get `\\d`.
- The predicate is defined in a literal `NSString`, therefore the backslash has to be escaped again, and you get `\\\\d`.

You can avoid one escaping step if you use a `%@` format instead of a literal string in the predicate:

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\d{10}|\\d{9}[Xx]";
NSPredicate *isbnPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
```

Using `%@` for all variable parts in a predicate is generally better, because it avoids
all kinds of quoting and escaping problems.

Comment: Another question, why we can write it like `NSString *pattern = @"\\d{10}|\\d{9}[Xx]";` not `NSString *pattern = @"\\\\d{10}|\\\\d{9}[Xx]";`

Comment: @KudoCC: `NSString *pattern = @"\\\\d{10}|\\\\d{9}[Xx]"` is stored as the string `"\\d{10}|\\d{9}[Xx]"`, that would match a literal backslash character followed by 10 "d" characters.

Comment: But why it won't be escaped again in `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];`?

Comment: @KudoCC: the predicate is internally represented as NSComparisonPredicate , not as a string, so there will be no additional escaping. You just don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Majority of programming language use `\` for escape sequence.

When you write like:

```
 SELF MATCHES '\\\\d{10}|\\\\d{9}[Xx]'
```

Each \ will escape the next character and it'll become:

```
SELF MATCHES '\\d{10}|\\d{9}[Xx]'
```

**Why \d not used ?**

If you use like:

```
SELF MATCHES '\d{10}|\d{9}[Xx]'
```

In regex It'll be changed to:

```
SELF MATCHES 'd{10}|d{9}[Xx]'
```

**Why \d not used ?**

If you use like:

```
SELF MATCHES '\\d{10}|\\d{9}[Xx]'
```

In regex It'll be changed to:

```
SELF MATCHES '\d{10}|\d{9}[Xx]'
```

But in regular expression the `\d` will be treated as an escape sequence and it will take it as `d{10}|d{9}[Xx]`

Comment: "If you use:

SELF MATCHES '\d{10}|\d{9}[Xx]'
It'll be changed like:

SELF MATCHES 'd{10}|d{9}[Xx]'", Is it true?

Comment: @KudoCC: means it'll be treated as an escape sequence.